# What is wrong with my batch "IF ELSE" example?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I try to run the following code:

```
@echo off

IF (%4%=="true") (
     echo "First if" 
     powershell.exe -file "installRgExe2.ps1" %1 %2 %3 [] "true"
)
ELSE (
        IF (%5%=="true") (
            echo "Second if"
            powershell.exe -file "installRgExe2.ps1" %1 %2 %3 %4 "true"
        )
        ELSE (
            echo "Last else" 
            powershell.exe -file "installRgExe2.ps1" %1 %2 %3 %4 "false"
        )
)
```

And I get the error :

```
'ELSE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'ELSE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Because of the ELSE errors, the code from the ELSE block is executed, meaning "Last else" is printed...

So....what is wrong in my syntax ?:\

Comment: I think the `else` must be on the same line as the closing parentheses, so: `) ELSE (` on a single line

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name NOW i am getting this following error ") was unexpected at this time."

Comment: No idea, that works for me

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name is abslolutely right! But what is `%4%`, `%5%` supposed to be? if you are referring to command line arguments, then state `"%~4"` and `"%~5"`, respectively; if you really have got environment variables defined named `4`, `5`, then -- well -- just don't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`if`/`else`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) block is constructed wrongly, you have to make sure that `else` appears in the same line than the closing parenthesis of the command sequence behind `if` (type `if /?` into a command prompt window):

```cmd
if <condition> (
    <command sequence>
) else (
    <command sequence>
)
```

Note that the condition must not be parenthesised.

Then you are referring to [command line arguments](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) in a wrong way, there is no closing `%`-sign, so `%4%` and `%5%` is wrong, you must use `%4` and `%5`, respectively. But you have to make sure that quotation left and right of the comparison operator `==` are the same, because they are actually compared as well:

```cmd
if /I "%~4" == "true" (
    echo First if
    powershell.exe -file "installRgExe2.ps1" "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "" "true"
) else (
    if /I "%~5" == "true" (
        echo Second if
        powershell.exe -file "installRgExe2.ps1" "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "%~4" "true"
    ) else (
        echo Last else
        powershell.exe -file "installRgExe2.ps1" "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "%~4" "false"
    )
)
```

As you can see I explicitly put quotation marks like `"%~4"` and `"%~5"`; the `~` modifier removes potential quotation marks from the arguments in advance in order to avoid over-quotation.

The `/I` option is there to specify case-insensitive comparison; remove it if you do not want that.

Answer (score 1):

Quick example, *based upon the provided comments*:

```bat
@Echo Off
If "%~4" == "true" (
    Echo "First if"
    PowerShell -File ".\installRgExe2.ps1" "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "[]" "true"
) Else (
    If "%~5" == "true" (
        Echo "Second if"
        PowerShell -File ".\installRgExe2.ps1" "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "%~4" "true"
    ) Else (
        Echo "Last else"
        PowerShell -File ".\installRgExe2.ps1" "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "%~4" "false"
    )
)
```